# group by error sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
select 
    case location_id 
      when 1 then 'DELHI' when 2 then 'AHMEDABAD' 
      when 4 then 'HYDERABAD' when 5 then 'KOLKATA' when 6 then 'BANGALORE'
      when 7 then 'MUMBAI' when 8 then 'CHENNAI' 
   end as CITY,
   count(*) as Total
from #tmptab1
group by CITY
```

I get error

> *Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 12
>
>   Invalid column name 'CITY'*

How to rectify this ? Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use column aliases in `GROUP BY` clauses. Please see [Conceptual Order of Evaluation of a Select Statement](http://tinman.cs.gsu.edu/~raj/sql/node22.html), where you will see that the clauses are (logically) evaluated in this order: `FROM, WHERE, GROUP BY, HAVING, SELECT, DISTINCT, UNION, ORDER BY`.

That is not exactly how the engine performs the operation, but it is a useful heuristic for a solid practical understanding of why you can't use something from the `SELECT` statement in the `GROUP BY` clause -- it isn't logically available to the `GROUP BY` clause as it is evaluated later.

There are several ways around this:

1. Repeat the entire expression in the `GROUP BY` clause:

   ```
   SELECT
      City =
         CASE location_id when 1 then 'DELHI' when 2 then 'AHMEDABAD' 
         when 4 then 'HYDERABAD' when 5 then 'KOLKATA' when 6 then 'BANGALORE'
         when 7 then 'MUMBAI' when 8 then 'CHENNAI'
         END,
      Total = Count(*)
   FROM #tmptab1
   GROUP BY
      CASE location_id when 1 then 'DELHI' when 2 then 'AHMEDABAD' 
      when 4 then 'HYDERABAD' when 5 then 'KOLKATA' when 6 then 'BANGALORE'
      when 7 then 'MUMBAI' when 8 then 'CHENNAI'
      END
   ```
2. Use a derived table:

   ```
   SELECT
      City,
      Total = Count(*) 
   FROM
      (
         SELECT
            City =
               CASE location_id when 1 then 'DELHI' when 2 then 'AHMEDABAD' 
               when 4 then 'HYDERABAD' when 5 then 'KOLKATA' when 6 then 'BANGALORE'
               when 7 then 'MUMBAI' when 8 then 'CHENNAI'
               END
         FROM #tmptab1
      ) Cities
   GROUP BY City;
   ```
3. Use a Common Table Expression (CTE), SQL Server 2005 and up:

   ```
   WITH Cities AS (
       SELECT
          City =
             CASE location_id 
                when 1 then 'DELHI' 
                when 2 then 'AHMEDABAD' 
                when 4 then 'HYDERABAD' 
                when 5 then 'KOLKATA' 
                when 6 then 'BANGALORE'
                when 7 then 'MUMBAI' 
                when 8 then 'CHENNAI'
             END
       FROM #tmptab1
   )
   SELECT
      City,
      Total = Count(*) 
   FROM Cities
   GROUP BY City;
   ```
4. Use CROSS APPLY, SQL Server 2005 and up:

   ```
   SELECT
      City,
      Total = Count(*)
   FROM
      #tmptab1
      CROSS APPLY (
         SELECT
            City =
               CASE location_id when 1 then 'DELHI' when 2 then 'AHMEDABAD' 
               when 4 then 'HYDERABAD' when 5 then 'KOLKATA' when 6 then 'BANGALORE'
               when 7 then 'MUMBAI' when 8 then 'CHENNAI'
               END
      ) C
   GROUP BY City;
   ```

Since your expression is deterministic, it is possible that you could simply do `GROUP BY location_id`, however this is not the normal case, and you shouldn't go around expecting to be able to circumvent normal aggregate grouping logic by selecting a single column, because most of the time such a CASE expression adds value that is not deterministic.

In fact, because the information is not only deterministic but is about the real world (rather than the business rules) I would recommend that you NOT encode this information in your query! Create a `Location` table and join to it. It is not best practice to put changeable user data directly into queries--queries are supposed to record process, not content, and what if you add a new location_id? All the queries that use it will have to change. Additionally, grouping by `location_id` will not work properly if more than one `location_id` can refer to the same city.

Answer (score 2):

you cant use aliasses in group by statement
you will need the entire part from the select in your group by

```
select case location_id when 1 then 'DELHI' when 2 then 'AHMEDABAD' 
when 4 then 'HYDERABAD' when 5 then 'KOLKATA' when 6 then 'BANGALORE'
when 7 then 'MUMBAI' when 8 then 'CHENNAI' end as CITY,count(1) as Total
from #tmptab1
group by case location_id when 1 then 'DELHI' when 2 then 'AHMEDABAD' 
when 4 then 'HYDERABAD' when 5 then 'KOLKATA' when 6 then 'BANGALORE'
when 7 then 'MUMBAI' when 8 then 'CHENNAI' end
```

grouping on location_id itself might also work

Comment: you are welcome, in some cases the result might differ from the origional value. if 1 and 2 gave 'DELHI' you would have needed the entire statement or the results would have been wrong

Answer (score 1):

Following (*changing your query just by* `group by location_id`) works on `Sql-server 2008 or above` (not sure below)

```
select 
    case location_id 
      when 1 then 'DELHI' when 2 then 'AHMEDABAD' 
      when 4 then 'HYDERABAD' when 5 then 'KOLKATA' when 6 then 'BANGALORE'
      when 7 then 'MUMBAI' when 8 then 'CHENNAI' 
   end as CITY,
   count(*) as Total
from #tmptab1
group by location_id --NOTE
```

`Or` you can use

```
select case location_id when 1 then 'DELHI' when 2 then 'AHMEDABAD' 
            when 4 then 'HYDERABAD' when 5 then 'KOLKATA' when 6 then 'BANGALORE'
            when 7 then 'MUMBAI' when 8 then 'CHENNAI' 
            end as CITY, total
from (
    select location_id, count(*) total
    from #tmptab1 
    group by location_id ) A
```